# How to connect loopback to timescale db?

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopback4, timescaledb

I am trying to develop a loopback4 based backend application. I want to use Timescale DB as the database for the backend.

How can i connect loopback4 to timescale db?

Please let me know the kind of connector to use, and the the params of various dbsource fields.

Answer (score 0):

That should work the same as with other Postgresql connections.
If on the same machine, you can use localhost:5432

$POSTGRES_USER and $POSTGRES_PASSWORD have to be defined for postgresql in advance.